# Gradient Descent Divergence

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am curious about divergence conditions of the Gradient Descent method. In the reading that I have done I have only ever seen it mentioned that this method diverges when $\alpha$ is too large. It seems obvious to me though that the method could also diverge on an equation such as ${-x^3\over3}+x$ for any initial guess $x$ such that $x>1$. If the initial $x$ is greater than $1$ then the gradient descent method will always push you farther from the min regardless of what $\alpha$ you select because the slope you get from the derivative will always be negative which means you will always be increasing the value of your previous guess.

I am curious about this in the context of minimizing the error function of a neural network. When you do this you don't always have a graph of the function to look at to help identify what to pick as an initial guess. How is it possible to identify whether your minimization is diverging because you have selected an $\alpha$ that is too large or an initial guess that is in the wrong spot?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the case of $-x^3/3+x$ for initial conditions greater than $1$, gradient descent *does* send you to a "minimum", it's just that the "minimum value" is $-\infty$, attained at $+\infty$. This situation is usually prohibited by assumption in formal discussion of optimization algorithms (even when we don't assume convexity). Anyway, what is your question?

Comment: I rephrased your last sentence as a question - hope this was right.

Comment: For this question I was thinking about edge cases where gradient decent might diverge in the error function of neural network training. When using it to optimize the error function of a neural network we randomly select the starting $x$ from our domain. I don't see why it would not be possible to select a starting $x$ that fits the case mentioned here. If it is possible then how would I identify if I need to change my starting $\alpha$ or my starting $x$ to make the algorithm converge to the minimum.

Comment: The definition of the error function for ANNs prevents such an occurrence; usually the error is guaranteed to be positive, so it won't diverge forever. And, indeed, reaching such a minimum would be the goal! Such divergences are handled with regularization in other algorithms sometimes too. There is an issue of overfitting, but that can only be handled separately. The main issue is local minima in the landscape... that is why stochastic gradient descent is often used.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand, if we use something like SSE as our error metric the error will always be positive. This means we the error can never descend to $-\infty$. Does the summation also guarantee that the tails will go towards $+\infty$? If the error function is guaranteed to be concave upward it is easy to see that GD will always find a local min with a small enough $\alpha$, but I am not sure if this guarantee exists or if it is necessary.